# Any benefit of using assert instead of using a simple "if" ?

Tags: c, if-statement, assert

Given this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  assert (somePtr!=NULL);
  printf ("%d\n",*somePtr);
}

int main ()
{
  int a=1234;
  int * b = NULL;
  int * c = NULL;

  b=&a;

  print_number (c);
  print_number (b);

  return 0;
}
```

I can do this instead :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  if (somePtr != NULL)
       printf ("%d\n",*somePtr);
  // else do something 
}

int main ()
{
  int a=1234;
  int * b = NULL;
  int * c = NULL;

  b=&a;

  print_number (c);
  print_number (b);

  return 0;
}
```

So , what am I gaining by using assert ?

Regards

Comment: Perhaps you should have tagged C instead of C++. C headers only, C functions only.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: in C it would have been int main(void) ;)

Comment: I guess I missed that :D It was more of a slight hint to OP that if he is going to use C++ he might as well make use of its headers and features.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`assert` is to document your assumptions in the code. `if` statement is to handle different logical scenarios.

Now in your specific case, think from the point of view of the developer of the `print_number()` function.

For example when you write

```
void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  assert (somePtr!=NULL);
  printf ("%d\n",*somePtr);
}
```

you mean to say that,

In my `print_number` function I **assume** that **always** the pointer coming is not null. I would be **very very surprised** if this is null. I don't care to handle this scenario at all in my code.

But, if you write

```
void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  if (somePtr != NULL)
       printf ("%d\n",*somePtr);
  // else do something 
}
```

You seem to say that, in my `print_number` function, I **expect** people to pass a null pointer. And I know how to handle this situation and I do handle this with an `else` condition.

So, sometimes you will know how to handle certain situations and you want to do that. Then, use `if`.
Sometimes, you assume that something will not happen and you don't care to handle it. You just express your surprise and stop your program execution there with assert.

Answer (score 14):

The difference is that [`assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) is enabled only for **debug** build; it is not enabled for **release** build (i.e when `NDEBUG` is defined), which means in the release build there will be no check; as a result, your code will be little bit faster, compared to the one in which you use `if` condition which remains in the release build as well.

That means, `assert` is used to check common errors when you write the code, and catch them as soon as possible, in the development phase itself.

Comment: So then, if it is removed during production build, is it safe to assume that after through debugging there should never be a case in which the assertion is violated? Or would one need to replace it with an if?

Answer (score 10):

Lots of reasons:

1. Asserts are usually removed for release builds.
2. Asserts will report failure information to the client. `if()` does nothing by itself.
3. Because asserts are usually macros, you can also get code information about the failing assertion.
4. Assert is more semantically clear than `if()`.

Answer (score 7):

If assertion fails, you will see the output containing the failed assertion itself, plus the function and the line of the failed assert, something like:

```
test: main.cpp:9: int main(): Assertion `0==1' failed.
```

So, if your program crashes in runtime, you will see the exact reason and location of the crash.
There's a big article about assertions in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 3):

Assert will inform you that something wrong happend, possibly error to be fixed. In debug mode it will break and show callstack that will help you with fixing bug. So its a good practice to use. I would actually use if() and assert, because in Release your asserts should be turned off:

```
void print_number(int* somePtr) {
  assert(somePtr != NULL);
  if (somePtr != NULL)
       printf ("%d\n",*somePtr);
  // else do something 
}
```

in "      // else do something " you might think of throwing exception or returning error code.

Answer (score 1):

If Your (if) statement becomes True or False so compiler go for the next instructions.
But in assert.h when your statement becomes false "Program Terminates immediately" with assertion message.

EXAMPLE :*

```
#include <assert.h> #include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int a;
    printf("Enter an integer value: "); scanf("%d", &a); assert(a >= 10);
    printf("Integer entered is %d\n", a);
    return(0); }
```